# Javascript performance drop when drawing multiple object

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've created a canvas where I draw 100 cubes, each with a diffrent speed, position and size. It runs just as i'd expect at the frame rate I want.

But when I switch to a diffrent programe it takes a few seconds for my laptop to adjust, so I'm unable to use any program for a few seconds, I think this might be because of the script and when I take a look at task manager my GPU usage goes up to 40%

Here is the code:

```
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

  c.setAttribute('width', w);
  c.setAttribute('height', h);

  var Ypos = [];
  var Xpos = [];
  var cubeWidth = [];
  var Yspeed = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) cubeWidth[i] = getRandomInt(7, 10);
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) Yspeed[i] = getRandomInt(30, 90) / 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) Ypos[i] = getRandomInt(0, c.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) Xpos[i] = getRandomInt(0, c.width);

  setInterval( function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    Ypos[i] += Yspeed[i];

    if (Ypos[i] + cubeWidth[i] / 2 > h) {
    Ypos[i] = -cubeWidth[i] / 2;
    Xpos[i] = getRandomInt(0, c.width);
    }

    var width = 10;
    var height = 10;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(-cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Xpos[i], -cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Ypos[i]);
    ctx.lineTo(cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Xpos[i], -cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Ypos[i]);
    ctx.lineTo(cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Xpos[i], cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Ypos[i]);
    ctx.lineTo(-cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Xpos[i], cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Ypos[i]);
    ctx.lineTo(-cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Xpos[i], -cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Ypos[i]);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  }, 1000/60);

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
```

what could I do to fix this problem?

Comment: what do you mean with " tap out of the website"

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is, but maybe you should take a look at [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). This will run the code only when the page has focus, and only at the refresh-rate of the monitor.

Comment: @CalvinNunes He probably means "ta*b* out of the program"

Comment: @CalvinNunes I did indeed mean tab out of the program to a diffrent one, I've updated the question to be a bit more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `setInterval()` as that's definitely going to cause a problem and require the browser keeps active, even when the OS is trying to do other things.  Wrap the drawing in a function of its own and make that function call itself when it's done, but use `requestAnimationFrame()` so it only draws when the window is active...

```
function() draw {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
        Ypos[i] += Yspeed[i];

        if (Ypos[i] + cubeWidth[i] / 2 > h) {
            Ypos[i] = -cubeWidth[i] / 2;
            Xpos[i] = getRandomInt(0, c.width);
        }

        var width = 10;
        var height = 10;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Xpos[i], -cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Ypos[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Xpos[i], -cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Ypos[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Xpos[i], cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Ypos[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(-cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Xpos[i], cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Ypos[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(-cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Xpos[i], -cubeWidth[i] / 2 + Ypos[i]);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }, 1000 / 60);
}

// start the animation
draw();
```

You can find out more about `requestAnimationFrame()` here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: The browser scales down `setInterval` rate when the tab isn't active, that should not pose a problem. (Yes, raf is to be preferrred, you don't even need the setTimeout)

Comment: @Bergi - Doesn't that depend on the browser (the scaling down)?  Thanks for the info though.  Also, I always wrap `requestAnimationFrame()` in a timeout so it sets the maximum frame rate.  I'm quite anal :)

Comment: @Archer That last word in your comment is a bit unlucky, mind to reword that?

Comment: @chade_ Maybe it is.  Maybe it isn't :)

Comment: @Archer thanks! it solves when I tab out :), there is this less annoying bug, when i move the mouse quickly around the screen the frame rate drops and cubes slow down, you dont happen to know why?

Comment: @Schotsl That's just computers for you.  Give them more to do and they take longer to do it :)